# Why does my program ask me to input a value for self?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am making a card game in python. I used the code for a class of a stack that I found online :

```
class Stack:

  def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

  def isEmpty(self):
     return self.items == []

  def push(self, item):
     self.items.insert(0,item)

  def pop(self):
     return self.items.pop(0)

  def peek(self):
     return self.items[0]
```

When I run this its all fine however when I try to call any of the behaviours my program asks me to pass in a value for self, as if it was a parameter. I feel like Im going crazy...

When this code is run :

```
  Cards = []
  Cards = Stack()
  Cards = Stack.push(15)
  Cards = Stack.peek()
  Cards = Stack.pop()
```

When the 3rd line is run this error is displayed :

```
TypeError: push() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'
```

When I pass in the value of None like this

```
Cards = Stack.push(None,15)
```

I am left with another error :

```
self.items.insert(0,item)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Check out this link https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0   They cover the concept of `self` with Python in painful depth and should be able to give you a solid understanding of why you are getting that error

Comment: Also, if `Cards` is an instance of `Stack` why are you calling `Cards = Stack.push(15)`?  Shouldn't you just be doing something like `Cards.push(15)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After declaring `Cards` to be an instance of `Stack`, you don't need to refer to `Stack` anymore.  Just use `Cards`.

```
Cards = Stack()
Cards.push(15)
x = Cards.peek()
y = Cards.pop()
```

Also, the first line of code `Cards = []` is useless, as you immediately reassign `Cards` to be something else.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reassign `Cards` on each line. `Cards` is the `Stack` object, it needs to stay the same. It should be used as the variable with which you call all the other methods.

```
Cards = Stack()
Cards.push(15)
item = Cards.peek()
item2 = Cards.pop() # item == item2
```